# Passing Variable into Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

Hey there Stack Users,

I have been frustrated with this problem for about two hours now and don't know what I am doing wrong. I am calling a method `send_intro_email`on an update action for a `User`. The `send_intro_email` method calls a `NotificationMailer` method named `intro_email(user)`.

The problem I am having is the data for `user` is being passed all the way until the point of where it is used inside .erb email. I tested it and it actually is being passed but don't know why I can't use it inside the email itself.

Files:

`notificaion_mailer.rb`

```
def intro_email(user)
   puts user # works
   mail(to: "email", from: "email2", subject: "THIS IS A TEST")
end
```

`User.rb`

```
def send_intro_email 
  NotificationMailer.intro_email(self).deliver
end
```

`intro_email.erb`

```
The users name is <%= user.name %>.
```

I can show an error message later when I get on my other PC if needed. Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are using local variable `user`, which has scope only to the method you have defined. You have to use instance variable `@user` as an example. So changes are to be done like :

```
def intro_email(user)
   @user = user
   mail(to: "email", from: "email2", subject: "THIS IS A TEST")
end
```

Then inside the view use `@user`. Like

```
The users name is <%= @user.name %>.
```

Comment: Hey Arup, I actually did try that and I didn't receive an error, but it output @user.name instead of "Bob" or whatever when the email was sent.

Comment: @Matt-L change the name as intro_email.text.erb (this is for text email). Try and get back to me

Comment: I will try that when I get home and let you know how it works. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. The thing is that I really thought I saved the file as text.erb to start but I guess not. 

I'm not sure how to mark you answer as the answer from a comment.